# How to Check an Email Used for User Registration in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to validate a user details being registered in `Meteor.users` collection.

I know that I can check username uniqueness by simply querying the db field `username` of the `Meteor.users`; i.e.

```
var obj = Meteor.users.findOne({username:userId});
if (obj!=null) {
   alert('Username is already in use');
}
```

But how do I check the uniqueness of the email as well? Because from the documentation, the `emails` is an array of an object with `address` and `verified` fields. How do I consturct the filter for this?

Comment: See [docs on Meteor.users](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users).  `Meteor.users.findOne( {'emails.address': "example@email.com"})` is the short answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't have to do this. If you tried to insert a document where someone already has the email address it wouldn't allow it. The `emails.address` is set as a unique key and mongo wouldn't allow it to be inserted.

It is a good idea to get the error at the point of insertion than to use `Meteor.users.findOne()` on the browser side.

This is because you would need to publish all the users email's for the code to work on the browser and this wouldn't be 1) scalable and 2) bad from a privacy standpoint.

Another option is to check whether the email exists with Meteor.call and Meteor methods if you want to display a dynamic status label on whether the address is available or not.

Comment: The problem is the returned error is in English, while my customer will be using other language. Speaking of that, how is localization handled in Meteor?

Comment: @HaikalNashuha sorry I just saw this. you mention a good point. The meteor core files aren't translated yet. Something you could do is check the reason you get back with `err.reason` in the `Accounts.createUser` callback and translate it before you display it from a list of known errors.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
include 'include/config.php';
//$sql=$dbset->query("select * from registries WHERE email_id LIKE'".$_POST['email']."'");
$sql=mysql_query("select * from registries WHERE email_id LIKE '".$_POST['email']."'");
echo $count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
?>
```

Comment: someone is really trying too hard to get SO points. This is not meteor, it is PHP. Downvoted.